# query execution time is more in NamedParameterJdbcTemplate than mySql

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-jdbc

I am using spring NamedParameterJdbcTemplate with my sql.I am executing 2 queries through jbdc template it is taking 1.1 and 4 s respectively. but the same query if I am running in my sql it is taking 0.5 and 1 s respectively I don't understand what could be my bottleneck. my application and db resides on same server so there can be no network overhead, I have my connection pooled. I can say it is working because query with less amount of data taking 50 ms through application. please let me know what could be my bottleneck

below is my code of namedjdbcTemplate

```
MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        parameters.addValue("organizationIds", list);
        parameters.addValue("fromDate", fromDate);
        parameters.addValue("toDate", toDate);
        long startTime =  System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<MappingUI> list =namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(QueryList.CALCULATE_SCORE,parameters,new RowMapper<MappingUI>() {

            @Override
            public MappingUI mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                MappingUI mapping=  new MappingUI();
                mapping.setCompetitor(rs.getInt("ID"));
                mapping.setTotalRepufactScore(rs.getFloat("AVG_SCORE"));
                return mapping;
            }
        });
```

below is my query

```
SELECT AVG(SCORE.SCORE) AS AVG_SCORE,ANALYSIS.ID AS ID FROM  SCORE SCORE,QC_ANALYSIS ANALYSIS WHERE SCORE.TAG_ID = ANALYSIS.ID AND                                     ANALYSIS.ORGANIZATION_ID IN (:organizationIds) AND DATE(ANALYSIS.DATES) BETWEEN DATE(:fromDate) AND DATE(:toDate)                                     GROUP BY ANALYSIS.ORGANIZATION_ID
```

Comment: First of all you are comparing Apples and Oranges. Query execution time on the DB server isn't the same as using JDBC to execute a query and you also include the time to map to/from an object. So at least those comparisons aren't fair. The `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` does a lot of `String` replacement it replaces the `:parameter` with a `?` before executing the query (due to JDBC not supporting named parameters) and `String` replacement can take some time. In short there is no overhead you are comparing the wrong things.

Comment: But my execution time is more than 4x times of what it takes in direct query. how can I reduce it?

Comment: As stated you are comparing apples and oranges, yes it will be slower (overhead for String replacement and overhead for creating a result per row). So again you are comparing apples and oranges.